# Помогите вытащить историю заказов в отдельный блок. Битрикс. filter_history

Tags: php, битрикс

Доброго времени суток. В личном кабинете есть вкладки на которых я вывожу "текущие заказы" и должен вывести "историю заказов", но она спрятана в отдельной ссылке...[image: Вот это надо в отдельный блок]

```
<div class="row col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <?
        $nothing = !isset($_REQUEST["filter_history"]) && !isset($_REQUEST["show_all"]);
        $clearFromLink = array("filter_history", "filter_status", "show_all", "show_canceled");

        if ($nothing || $_REQUEST["filter_history"] == 'N') {
            ?>
            <a class="sale-order-history-link"
               href="<?= $APPLICATION->GetCurPageParam("filter_history=Y", $clearFromLink, false) ?>">
                <?
                echo Loc::getMessage("SPOL_TPL_VIEW_ORDERS_HISTORY") ?>
            </a>
            <?
        }
        if ($_REQUEST["filter_history"] == 'Y') {
            ?>
            <a class="sale-order-history-link" href="<?= $APPLICATION->GetCurPageParam("", $clearFromLink, false) ?>">
                <?
                echo Loc::getMessage("SPOL_TPL_CUR_ORDERS") ?>
            </a>
            <?
            if ($_REQUEST["show_canceled"] == 'Y') {
                ?>
                <a class="sale-order-history-link"
                   href="<?= $APPLICATION->GetCurPageParam("filter_history=Y", $clearFromLink, false) ?>">
                    <?
                    echo Loc::getMessage("SPOL_TPL_VIEW_ORDERS_HISTORY") ?>
                </a>
                <?
            } else {
                ?>
                <a class="sale-order-history-link"
                   href="<?= $APPLICATION->GetCurPageParam("filter_history=Y&show_canceled=Y", $clearFromLink, false) ?>">
                    <?
                    echo Loc::getMessage("SPOL_TPL_VIEW_ORDERS_CANCELED") ?>
                </a>
                <?
            }
        }
    ?>
    </div>
    <?
if (!count($arResult['ORDERS'])) {
        ?>
        <div class="row col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <a href="<?= htmlspecialcharsbx($arParams['PATH_TO_CATALOG']) ?>" class="sale-order-history-link">
                <?= Loc::getMessage('SPOL_TPL_LINK_TO_CATALOG') ?>
            </a>
        </div>
        <?
    }

    if ($_REQUEST["filter_history"] !== 'Y') {
        $paymentChangeData = array();
        $orderHeaderStatus = null;

        foreach ($arResult['ORDERS'] as $key => $order) {
            if ($orderHeaderStatus !== $order['ORDER']['STATUS_ID'] && $arResult['SORT_TYPE'] == 'STATUS') {
                $orderHeaderStatus = $order['ORDER']['STATUS_ID'];

                ?>
                <h1 class="sale-order-title1">
                    <?= Loc::getMessage('SPOL_TPL_ORDER_IN_STATUSES') ?>
                    &laquo;<?= htmlspecialcharsbx($arResult['INFO']['STATUS'][$orderHeaderStatus]['NAME']) ?>&raquo;
                </h1>
                <?
            }
            ?>
```

Вот сам код. Что необходимо сделать? Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: А что не получается? Совсем ничего? Тогда есть два пути. Первый на каждой вкладки разместить компонент выводящий историю заказов, на одной выводите только текущие, на другой все остальные. Или можете модифицировать существующий разделив вывод информации на две вкладки, но это скорее всего будет сложнее.

Comment: Да все верно, так бы я и сделал:) Проблема заключается в том, что история заказов выводится в виде personal/?filter_history=Y такой ссылки)
Что я делаю?
Я беру один компонент, ставлю его на обе вкладки...
У одного шаблон дефолтный, второй обозвал order_list_history.
И вот надо все данные из истории выдернуть...
Из-за фильтра этого и не знаю как сделать правильно.

Comment: посмотрите в настройках компонента, уверен, что можно отключить filter_history

Comment: Вчера все решили.
$_REQUEST["filter_history"] = 'Y';
Эту строчку надо прописать перед подключением самого компонента "sale.personal.order.list"